# '_WIN32_WINNT' / 'WINVER' : macro redefinition

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-xp

I have a `VS2015 C++` project. app has to run on both Windows 7 and XP. So, I want to set `_WIN32_WINNT` & `WINVER` to `_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP`.

This is how `stdafx.h` of my project looks like:

**stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define _WIN32_WINNT        _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP         
#define WINVER              _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP   

#include <WinSDKVer.h>

// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>
```

When compiled, I see the following warning/error:

```
stdafx.h(12): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>stdafx.h(12): warning C4005: '_WIN32_WINNT': macro redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\SDKDDKVer.h(197): note: see previous definition of '_WIN32_WINNT'
1>stdafx.h(13): warning C4005: 'WINVER': macro redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\SDKDDKVer.h(212): note: see previous definition of 'WINVER'
```

Comment: you not need direct  `#define _WIN32_WINNT' - simply remove this

Comment: or add this line `#define _CHICAGO_`

Comment: Do take a look at targetver.h, follow the directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `#include "targetver.h"` is including `<sdkddkver.h>` which already defines the constants _WIN32_WINNT and WINVER when they aren't already defined by the build environment.

As a matter of fact, the auto-generated `targetver.h` tells you exactly how to fix this:

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Simple solution. Just define those constants before the inclusion of `targetver.h`. You might have to use the actual literal value for XP since you haven't include the header file that defines

Like this:

```
// x501 is XP
#define _WIN32_WINNT        0x0501         
#define WINVER              0x0501  

#include "targetver.h"
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Is there a solution using names like _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP instead of numerical constants like 0x0501 ?

Comment: @Liviu - everything you need is in `<sdkddkver.h>`

Comment: yes, but I have to define `_WIN32_WINNT` before including `<sdkddkver.h>`, don't I ? And accept warning `C4005: '_WIN32_WINNT': macro redefinition`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#include <winsdkver.h>
#undef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

You #include <winsdkver.h> so you can use _WIN32_WIN_WINXP. However, then you need to #undef _WIN32_WINNT because it is defined in <winsdkver.h>.  That way when you use  #define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP you don't get the redefinition of _WIN32_WINNT warning.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.